# How can i read a csv file swiftUI

Tags: csv, swiftui

I am currently trying to read in a CSV file but am having some problems :(

Here is my CSV reader function

```
import SwiftUI

extension String{
    //Get the filename from a String
    func fileName ( ) -> String{
        return URL (fileURLWithPath: self).deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    }
    //Get the file extension from a String
    func fileExtension() -> String{
        return URL (fileURLWithPath: self).pathExtension
    }
    
}

func readCSV (inputFile: String, separator: String) -> [String]{
    //Split the file name
    let fileExtension = inputFile.fileExtension()
    let fileName = inputFile.fileName()
    //Get the file URL
    let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let inputFileURL = fileURL[0].appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension(fileExtension)
    //Get Data
    do{
        let savedData = try String(contentsOf: inputFileURL)
        return savedData.components(separatedBy: separator)
    } catch{
        return ["Error file cant be found"]
    }
}
```

and then in the view, I try to display it like

```
struct Test: View{
    
    var data = readCSV(inputFile: "capitals.csv", separator: ",")
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(data[0])
            
        }
}
```

When I run the app I all get is `Error file can't be found

[My CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esVHP.jpg)

How can I displays the data in my view Please

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have added CSV file in the document directory or you have added it to your project?

Comment: It is in my project and documents

Comment: Add code where you have added this file in your document directory

Comment: Just a guess: the testing-environment has it's own "Document" folder in `/Users/[username]/Library/Containers/[Bundle Identifier]/Data/Documents`

Comment: Have you dragged and droped the file `capitals.csv` from `Finder` into your Xcode project?
 Or, did you add `capitals.csv` directly into the folder: `file:///Users/[username]/Library/Containers/[Bundle Identifier]/Data/Documents/capitals.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop the file `capitals.csv` from `Finder` into your Xcode project, the left panel where you can see the folders/files of your project.
Then use the following example code to read the `csv` data and display it (Country, Capital) in a `List`, works well for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // [Country:Capital]
    @State var capitals: [String:String] = [:]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(Array(capitals.keys), id: \.self) { country in
                VStack {
                    Text(country)
                    Text(capitals[country] ?? "no data")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            capitals = readCSV(inputFile: "capitals.csv")
        }
    }
    
    func readCSV(inputFile: String) -> [String:String] {
        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: inputFile, ofType: nil) {
            do {
                let fileContent = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
                let lines = fileContent.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                var results: [String:String] = [:]
                lines.dropFirst().forEach { line in
                    let data = line.components(separatedBy: ",")
                    if data.count == 2 {
                        results[data[0]] = data[1]
                    }
                }
                return results
            } catch {
                print("error: \(error)") // to do deal with errors
            }
        } else {
            print("\(inputFile) could not be found")
        }
        return [:]
    }
  
}
```

Comment: did my answer worked for you?